# how can i get page number of a string with is part of paragraph in word document using java

Tags: java, ms-word, aspose, aspose.words

I am using aspose-words library's node collection to read a word document node by node if a node is a paragraph and length is more that 8000 characters i am dividing it into sub-strings. The paragraphs exceeding one page most of the times.How can i get page number of the sub-string which i divided from that paragraph.

```
Document document=new Document(filePath);
LayoutCollector layoutCollector=new LayoutCollector(doc);
NodeCollection paragraphNodes=document.getChildNodes(NodeType.Paragraph,true);
for(Node node:paragraphNodes)
{
 if(node.getType==NodeType.PARAGRAPH){
 int pageNumber=layoutCollector.getStartPageIndex(node);
 List<String> subStrings=new ArrayList();
 Paragraph paragraph=(Paragraph) node;
 String text=paragraph.getText();
 if(text.length()>8000){
  //divideParagraph(String text) takes a string and returns ArrayList<Strings> each 
  String less than 8000 length
  subStrings.addAll(divideParagraph(text));
 }
 for(String subString:subStrings)
 {
 System.out.println("need the page number of each substring ");
 }
}
```

currently i am able to get start page and end page of a specific paragraph using layoutCollector but looking for sub-string's page number which i divide from paragraph because i have to report it in log. Is there any other library with which i can read all elements like paragraph, table , wordart etc having tract of pagenumber and line number where it starts.

Answer (score 2):

As you know there is no concept of page or line in MS Word documents due to their flow nature. The consumer applications build document layout on the fly, the same does Aspose.Words using it’s own layout engine. [LayoutCollector](https://reference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/layoutcollector/) and [LayoutEnumerator](https://reference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/layoutenumerator/) classes provides a limited access to document layout information.

If you would like to determine on which page part of the paragraph is located you should loop through paragraph's child nodes and and use `LayoutCollector.getStartPageIndex` or `LayoutCollector.getEndPageIndex`. But you should note, that even the "smallest" text node - `Run` can span several pages. So if you need exactly determine position where paragraph flows to the next page, it is required to split content in the paragraph into smaller peeces, for example into words.

For example the following code demonstrates a basic technique to read document content line by line:

```java
Document doc = new Document("C:\\Temp\\in.docx");
    
// Split all Run nodes in the document to make them not more than one word.
Iterable<Run> runs = doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.RUN, true);
for (Run r : runs)
{
    Run current = r;
    while (current.getText().indexOf(' ') >= 0)
        current = SplitRun(current, current.getText().indexOf(' ') + 1);
}
    
// Wrap all runs in the document with bookmarks to make it possible to work with LayoutCollector and LayoutEnumerator
runs = doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.RUN, true);
    
ArrayList<String> tmpBookmakrs = new ArrayList<String>();
int bkIndex = 0;
for (Run r : runs)
{
    // LayoutCollector and LayoutEnumerator does not work with nodes in header/footer or in textboxes.
    if (r.getAncestor(NodeType.HEADER_FOOTER) != null || r.getAncestor(NodeType.SHAPE) != null)
        continue;
        
    String bkName = "r" + bkIndex;
    r.getParentNode().insertBefore(new BookmarkStart(doc, bkName), r);
    r.getParentNode().insertAfter(new BookmarkEnd(doc, bkName), r);
        
    tmpBookmakrs.add(bkName);
    bkIndex++;
}
    
// Now we can use collector and enumerator to get runs per line in MS Word document.
LayoutCollector collector = new LayoutCollector(doc);
LayoutEnumerator enumerator = new LayoutEnumerator(doc);
    
Object currentLine = null;
int pageIndex = -1;
for (String bkName : tmpBookmakrs)
{
    Bookmark bk = doc.getRange().getBookmarks().get(bkName);
        
    enumerator.setCurrent(collector.getEntity(bk.getBookmarkStart()));
    while (enumerator.getType() != LayoutEntityType.LINE)
        enumerator.moveParent();
        
    if (currentLine != enumerator.getCurrent())
    {
        currentLine = enumerator.getCurrent();
            
        System.out.println();
        if(pageIndex!=enumerator.getPageIndex())
        {
            pageIndex = enumerator.getPageIndex();
            System.out.println("-------=========Start Of Page " + pageIndex + "=========-------");
        }
        System.out.println("-------=========Start Of Line=========-------");
    }
        
    Node node = bk.getBookmarkStart().getNextSibling();
    if (node != null && node.getNodeType() == NodeType.RUN)
        System.out.print(((Run)node).getText());
}
```

```java
private static Run SplitRun(Run run, int position)
{
    Run afterRun = (Run)run.deepClone(true);
    run.getParentNode().insertAfter(afterRun, run);
    afterRun.setText(run.getText().substring(position));
    run.setText(run.getText().substring(0, position));
    return afterRun;
}
```